# How to display items vertically one by one in css?

Tags: css

I have a dropdown menu, like:

```css
.dropdown {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
    <div class="dropdown">
        <input type="checkbox"> Foo <span> This is foo </span>
        <input type="checkbox"> Bar <span> This is bar </span>
    </div>
```

But in the snippet you can see that everything is displayed in it's own new line. How to make it inside one line, that would be displayed one by one vertically?

My expected result:

`Checkbox Foo This is foo
 Checkbox Bar This is bar`

Comment: Is using flexbox required here?

Comment: @j08691 no, it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change column to row as i did

```css
.dropdown {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
        <div class="dropdown">
          <input type="checkbox"> Foo <span> This is foo </span>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <input type="checkbox"> Bar <span> This is bar </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Then it's displayed as inline, not one by one vertically.

Comment: Okay wait I will post it

Comment: Check it now, HELPME.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should do it:

```
.dropdown {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

<div class="dropdown">
 <div class="child"><input type="checkbox"> Foo <span> This is foo </span></div>
 <div class="child"><input type="checkbox"> Bar <span> This is bar </span></div>  
</div>
```

I have just specified `div class="child"` to understand how it works.

When specifying this in a div, as a child of the parent container dropdown, you will automatically get div "child" as a row block while the parent container will take all the `child` divs and stack them up as a column due to `flex-direction: column`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap a `div` around each `input`

```css
.dropdown {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div>
     <input type="checkbox"> Foo <span> This is foo </span>
  </div>
  <div>
     <input type="checkbox"> Bar <span> This is bar </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

no need to put css style, Only using following code you can get expected output.

```
  <div class="dropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" >  Foo <span> This is foo<br>
        <input type="checkbox" >  Bar <span> This is bar
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapping `span`.

```css
.dropdown {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
    <div class="dropdown">
        <span><input type="checkbox"> Foo <span> This is foo </span></span>
        <span><input type="checkbox"> Bar <span> This is bar </span></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to use flexbox, just alter your html a bit

```html
    <div class="dropdown">
        <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Foo <span> This is foo </span>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Bar <span> This is bar </span>
        </label>
    </div>
```